# Mui Select with native=true doesn't fire onOpen event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use onOpen with MUI's Select component but it won't fire with native=true. I need to have this event fire with native select and in the documentation it isn't mentioned that native disables onOpen function. Anyone know why or how to get it to work?

I've tried to find some answers online but none that really gave any answers.

heres a codesandbox where you'll see I tried to console onOpen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-night-fyz3eg?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works only if `native = false`
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/b5d1b54562372268b6ec7e1b70fb2192442c08ba/packages/mui-material/src/Select/Select.js#L98

> * Callback fired when the component requests to be opened.    
> *
> Use it in either controlled (see the `open` prop), or uncontrolled
> mode (to detect when the Select expands).    *    
> * @param {object}
> event The event source of the callback.    
> *   **onOpen**:
> PropTypes.func   
>     
> * If `true`, the component is shown.    
> * You
> can only use it when the `native` prop is `false` (default).
> ***open**: PropTypes.bool,

Comment: thanks, this should be included in the docs for MUI